# MySQL update multiple paragraphs in a single field

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure how to word this but my problem is that my fields will not update properly.  I have a page set up where the user can update things like job listings, events, etc.  The problem is that some of the descriptions are 3 or more paragraphs long and when the form is processed, it doesn't update the database correctly.  This also happens when the user makes a new item.

Is there a limit on how much text can be loaded at once?

Here is the code for updating that I am using:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_workers_club SET eventdate='".$newDate."', theme='".$theme."', text='".$text."', contactperson='".$contactperson."', contactphone='".$phone."', dateentered='".$dateentered."' WHERE specialID='".$id."' ");
```

Here is the code for new items:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_workers_club (eventdate, theme, text, contactperson, contactphone, dateentered)
VALUES ('$newDate', '$theme', '$text', '$contactperson', '$contactphone', '$dateentered')");
```

I did not see another question like this so if you know of one let me know.

Comment: No there's no limit (not exactly), but show the _rest_ of your code. Are you escaping those variables before you insert them? If not, one of them could be breaking the query, especially likely if it is multiple paragraphs long, that it will contain a `'`.  `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: Seeing the database schema for the table would also help.

Comment: Are you passing in the variables directly from user-input? There's a chance that in some of the descriptions, there are apostrophes (`'`) which are interfering with the update.

Comment: I don't have any escapes for the variables and they are being passed directly.  I'll see if that can fix my issue.  It's only if the user enters a long paragraph but I didn't check if the paragraphs contained certain characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying what errors you're getting (or no errors) would greatly help diagnosing this problem. Is the content merely "cut off" in the database? Or is MySQL throwing errors back to PHP? However, here are some ideas...

mysql_real_escape_string() is a good place to start. Any input with a single apostrophe will break your code. Read up on cleansing user input for SQL, there are tons of resources on the web. It's absolutely not optional. Also look into parameterized queries / prepared statements, or one of the many ORM libraries/frameworks out there.

It's also possible that your "text" column is not large enough to hold those inputs, if you're only having problems for very long entries. VARCHAR(X) can only hold X characters. Use something like MEDIUMTEXT instead.

Use POST rather than GET; GET has limits on the size of values sent via the URL. POST is the conventional method when sending requests that create/alter data.

It's hard to say what the problem is without more info on what errors you're getting.

Comment: I believe I found a solution!  I changed to MEDIUMTEXT and I also used mysql_real_escape() and it worked.  The client's web host does not have command line access because they use a lower grade package so I'm stuck with phpmyadmin and can't change the max_allowed_packet as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

take a look to the setup of MySQL [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) `A communication packet is a single SQL statement sent to the MySQL server, a single row that is sent to the client, or a binary log event sent from a master replication server to a slave.`

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.global_variables where variable_name like 'max_allow%';
+--------------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME      | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+--------------------+----------------+
| MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET | 1048576        |
+--------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```